# Python - Matching two non-decreasing arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, search, match

I am working on the following question:
**Note: The code is to work under a time limit of 0.4 seconds, which requires a O(N+M) solution**
Your friend have given you a list of n positive integers: a0, a1, a2, ... an-1, in increasing order.

Now, your friend is going to ask you m questions, each of the form, "Here is a positive integer B. Is B a part of the list? **(B is in non-decreasing order)**"

Your task is to answer these questions. Output a single integer, which is the number of times you say "YES".

Input Format:
The first line of input will contain the integer n.

The second line of input will contain n positive integers, which is the list a, in increasing order.

The next line of input will contain the integer m, which is the number of questions.

The next m lines of input will each contain an integer B in **non-decreasing order**, which is the positive integer that your friend is asking you about.

Output Format:
Output should consist of a single integer, which is the number of times you say "YES".

Here is my code:

```
n = int(raw_input())
a = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
m = int(raw_input())
b = []
for y in range(0, m):
    b.append(int(raw_input()))

answer = 0
i = 0
j = 0
z = 1

while (i < n) and (j < m):
    if a[i] == b[j]:
        answer = answer + 1
        while ((z + j) < m):
            if a[i] == b[j + z]:
                answer = answer + 1
                z = z + 1
            elif a[i] != b[j + z]:
                i = i + 1
                j = j + z + 1
    elif a[i] < b[j]:
        i = i + 1
    elif a[i] > b[j]:
        j = j + 1

print answer
```

As the code may suggest, I am attempting to use a method that compares items in array A and array B, and if they don't match, add one to the index of the array with the smaller item. However, the code is not outputting the correct answer, and sometimes will loop on forever asking me for unlimited number of inputs.

I am a beginner at programming and I understand this is a very fundamental algorithm. I apologise in any statements not made clear or technical enough.

Thank you.

Comment: your logic seems quite obscure to me, you should probably explain in more details why you chose to update you indices your way. Also just by a quick glance at your code it seems to me that you forget to reset your indices to 0 (`z` and `i`) when you need to. Finally you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JulienBernu I am using this method to provide a O(N+M) solution that works under a 0.4 second time limit. In order to unrepeatedly call indices of A and B, i and j must be added by 1 every time two items 'matches' or 'does not match'. z is just there to calculate the possibilities of repeated values such as B = [1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6]. May I please ask if you may point out any mistakes regarding the indices because that is where I suspect the mistakes occurred. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a while loop here. That's why its running for infinite time. Just use a `for` loop. Also there are some very nice features in the python language that allow you to do this more quickly than iterating over the entire list yourself.

```
In [6]: count = 0

In [7]: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100]

In [8]: b = [1, 3, 1000, -10, 12]

In [9]: for val in b:
   ...:     if val in a:
   ...:         count += 1
   ...:

In [10]: print count
2
```

Julien Bernu has a more elegant idea:

```
a = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100])
b = set([1, 3, 1000, -10, 12])
print len(a.intersection(b))
```

Comment: @JulienBernu May I please ask how that works? Thank you.

Comment: @SunnyXu it's just math: you take the intersection of 2 sets i.e. the elements that belong to both sets, and just count how many elements are there (`len` does that).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. A for loop that checks over every single value would give an algorithmic complexity of O(N * M), which would time out on this problem, because I am looking for a code with an algorithmic complexity of O(N+M) that works for all values with A in increasing order and B in non-decreasing.

Comment: @JulienBernu Thank you. I tried     print len(list(set(a) & set(b)))    However, the question presented B in "non-decreasing" order, meaning it can be repeated, and A is the list that doesn't repeat. Do you know any ways to make the repeated values of B also be added using the len function? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can first keep track of how many times each element appear in `b` in a dictionary:

```
counts = {x: b.count(x) for x in b}
print sum(counts[x] for x in set(a).intersection(b))
```

Comment: Thank you. The code did work. However, it did not run under the time limit of 0.4 seconds which requires a O(N+M) solution. If possible, it would be very much appreciated if you may please find ways of improving or picking out mistakes in my original O(N+M) method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the helps. @Greg @JulienBernu I improve my code on my original logic and solved the problem. The solution is in O(N+M) and works within 0.25 seconds for all inputs.

```
n = int(raw_input())
a = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
m = int(raw_input())
b = []
for y in range(0, m):
    b.append(int(raw_input()))

answer = 0
i = 0
j = 0

while (i < n) and (j < m):
    if a[i] == b[j]:
        answer = answer + 1
        j = j + 1
    elif a[i] < b[j]:
        i = i + 1
    elif a[i] > b[j]:
        j = j + 1

print answer
```

Or for answer to all values when b is not in non-decreasing order, check if the list b is sorted using `all(b[i] <= b[i + 1] for i in xrange(m-1))`. If it is not sorted, use the method of binary search which I have previously used as a solution with O(Mlog(N)).